# How can you programatically change an Azure API Connection?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

How can you programatically change an Azure API Connection?

We have an API Connection pointing at a geo-replicated Azure SQL database, and as part of the failover, we need to change the connection details to the secondary SQL server

Checked in the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/) and can't see anything obvious as "API Connection", nor can I see anything in [Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/)

Comment: How does the implementation in logic app know about the failover?

Comment: @TusharJ At this stage, we're just querying the primary, and if we get 5 fails we're going to failover to the secondary, which involves switching the API Connection details ... appreciate this is hardly a robust solution!